# Run Phony targets only if certain files change

Tags: makefile, terraform

I want to run `Terraform fmt` command only if my `.tf/.tpl` files in the current directory or subdirectories have changed. Here is my makefile, not sure if this is even possible with makefile or not:

```
TF_VERSION=0.10.7

.PHONY: format

README.md: ./variables.tf
    terraform-docs md . > README.md

format: $(wildcard *.tf) $(wildcard */*.tf) $(wildcard */*.tpl)
    docker run -ti -v $(shell pwd):/tmp hashicorp/terraform:${TF_VERSION} fmt /tmp


help:
    @grep -E '^[a-zA-Z_-]+:.*?## .*$$' $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | sort | awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":.*?## "}; {printf "\033[36m%-30s\033[0m %s\n", $$1, $$2}'

.DEFAULT_GOAL := format
```

The problem is that `make` runs `format` every time (even without any changes), and if I remove the last line, I have to run `make format` otherwise it just runs the first rule.

Comment: Has changed since when? Has changed more recently than what?

Comment: @Beta Since last time you ran make command

Comment: PHONY targets are named as such because they are _intended_ for targets that don't actually build files. _In practice_ the difference is a PHONY target doesn't check file timestamps. A better name for it might've been ALWAYS.

Comment: @Andreas I like that interpretation as ALWAYS, thanks.

Comment: Your statement of the problem is that the target should not be run if some other criteria is met.  That directly contradicts what a phony target is; see the docs: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html  So, you cannot declare that target as `.PHONY`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an empty file, whose modification time records the last time the rule was run:

```
format_timestamp: $(wildcard *.tf) ...
    docker run -ti -v ...
    touch $@
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not phony. I guess the answer is it's not possible then.

Comment: @mok: Why do you want it to be phony? This is starting to sound like the XY problem.

Comment: Because I didn't want to add a file just to track when last time I ran make. Again, it seems  that it's not possible without another file or perhaps an over-engineered solution

Comment: @mok: If you want Make to act according to when it last ran that rule, it must record that time somewhere. There may be a way; are you willing to have Make run the rule unnecessarily on rare occasions?

Comment: Actually while I was responding to this comment, just realised that maybe I can add this file to gitignore, so I keep the repo clean (this file really should not end up on the repo), also will be able to track the changes on my local environment.

Comment: yep, working like a charm. Just maybe you could add this to your answer that it's not possible with a phony rule, or any rule that doesn't have a corresponding target file, so I can accept the answer. Thanks again btw